# Why getting unable to cast to type when casting generic method args to specific one?

Tags: java, junit4

I have written a java code for scientific calculator and also written jUnit test for it.Below is the method for calculating cubeRoot.

```
public <T> Double cubeRoot(T number){
    Double result= Math.cbrt((Double)number);
    return Math.abs(result);
}
```

Method returns proper result integer and double types,but when i invoke method for decimal,argument i pass is double type.Following are the JUint Test for above method.

```
public void testCalculateCubeRootWhenNegative(){
    Integer number=-64;
    assertEquals(-4.0,sci.cubeRoot(number));
}

public void testCalculateCubeRootOfdecimal(){
    Double number=0.40;
    assertEquals(0.736,sci.cubeRoot(number));
}
```

And this the interface i am using

```
public interface iScientific extends iMaths {
<T>Double squareRoot(T number);

<T>Double cubeRoot(T number);
```

Unable to find solution for getting error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying do to something like this:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(0);
Double d = (Double) i;
```

This does not work because `i` is not an instance of `Double`.

I suggest to change your `cubeRoot` method to accept a [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) (the base class of both `Integer` and `Double`):

```
public Double cubeRoot(Number number) {
  Double result = Math.cbrt(number.doubleValue());
  return Math.abs(result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Again i have do some more code change to make the code error free as initially error persist.Check the correction i have made and do suggest for more refactoring of code.

```
public Double cubeRoot(Number number){
    DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    double result= Math.cbrt(number.doubleValue());
    return Double.valueOf(df.format(result));
}
```

And the following test passed.

```
public void testCalculateCubeRootWhenNegative(){
    Integer number=-64;
    assertEquals(-4.0,sci.cubeRoot(number));
}
public void testCalculateCubeRootOfdecimal(){
    Double number=0.40;
    assertEquals(0.7368,sci.cubeRoot(number));
}
```

Comment: Hi koolmi. This site does not operate in the same way a normal forum does. You wrote this in the space reserved for answers to the question, but it isn't an answer.  If you have more information to add to your question, please edit the question. if you have another follow-up question , please ask a separate one. Please see the help pages for more information.